# Is Super server (inted / xinetd/... ) comes with Ubuntu default?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, xinetd, inetd

Few days back I learn about super server in networking. Then I looked for `/etc/inetd.conf` and `/etc/xinetd.d` and found neither of them in Ubuntu.

Note:

I know only these two types of super server configuration file in Unix like system.

Is Ubuntu still running `inetd` super server or it has been removed from system?

If it's running `inetd` super server then  where it's located?

Comment: Are you asking if Ubuntu comes with x/inetd installed by default (no), or how to configure your x/inetd service (after you have installed it)?

Comment: Ubuntu comes with x/inetd installed by default ?

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: @Braiam thanku :) Ubuntu doesn't comes with x/inetd installed by default .

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/faq.html) takes care of starting services. Restarting services as inetd can do is often not needed as the programs like `sshd` just start and run in the background, instead of being restarted again and again.

If you install some serial ports you might have to install `(x)inetd` to allow login over a serial line, but I haven't seen any need recently for other uses of `inetd`. That is not to say that it doesn't work, just that it has been marginalized by stability of specific daemons and no need to release memory that much on modern machines (like in the old days).

Systemd[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) once it percolates through from Debian to Ubuntu supports, AFAIK, more of `inetd` functionality than Upstart, but I don't know if it will prohibit its use.